# How to write an empty class, that initializes three object of another class

Tags: c++, class, oop, derived-class

I have to represent two classes, based of an UML diagram. I'll just upload the diagram here:

[image: UML Diagram]

As a specification, it is required that the program will create a Sale with three SaleItem objects. My issue is understanding how would one do so, inside a class with no parameters? I have attempted in doing so below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class SaleItem{
public:
    int code = 0;
    double price;
    SaleItem();
    SaleItem(double p){
        code++;
        price = p;

    }
};

class Sale:SaleItem{
public:
    Sale(){
        SaleItem o1 = SaleItem(12.5);
        SaleItem o2 = SaleItem(12.5);
        SaleItem o3 = SaleItem(12.5);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Sale one;
    return 0;
}
```

There has to be a better way of doing this, since I can't even access the created objects and use them. I could also be misunderstanding the UML diagram, but unfortunately it doesn't provide any other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white parallelogram at the end of the relation on the UML diagram means aggregation. That essentially means that the items are members of the sale. In other words, the sale class is not supposed to be empty.

The items cannot be direct members though since the upper limit is unspecified. I recommend storing the items in a `std::vector` member.

Comment: Just a small specification, the diagram on the paper has a dark parallelogram, but the one I recreated online didn't have that option. Same rules apply, right?

So in this case, it would be perfectly fine to add a vector member to Sale in which I store SaleItem members? If I could do so, then it's an easy fix.

Comment: The dark one means composition, and my answer applies even better to composition. Yes, add a vector member.